# how to add AIML library from program-ab in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, aiml

i have downloaded the program-ab and want to create a GUI java application for  chat bot but not sure how to add all resources in Netbeans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to add library in project and need to specify the path of bots folder from program-ab directory in object of org.alicebot.ab.Bot object

Comment: is there a download for `org.alicebot` jar files?